# GWT: RichTextArea is not auto-hiding PopupPanel

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

I have a PopuppupPanel with autoHide = true. It works perfect except for the case when I click on RichTextArea. If I click on it nothing happens and the PopupPanel is not autoClosed.

I examined the code which "autoCloses" the PopupPanel. When the panel is shown they add a Handler which looks like this:

```
nativePreviewHandlerRegistration = Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
      previewNativeEvent(event);
    }
  });
```

..and in previewNativeEvent(event) they hide the panel if certain conditions are met, especially MouseDownEvent is caught.

But it looks like RichTextArea is not firing MouseDownEvent! I cannot catch this event while debugging previewNativeEvent(event). Looks like I have to fire it manually. I fire it on the container of RichTextArea, or on its parent, which are HTMLPanel and div respectively:

```
myPanel.fire(new MouseDownEvent() {});
```

But this gives me no results: the event can be caught if I add MouseDownHandler on event targets, but it is not caught by the NativePreviewHandler I mentioned above.

So, finally:

1. Why my RichTextArea cannot "autoClose" my PopupPanel?
2. Am I right when I think that PreviewNativeEventHandler should catch all
   the events in the system and I can, for example, print to logs all
   the event in my app using that handler?
3. Why the PreviewNativeEvent Handler is not catching the MouseDown event from
   my RichtextArea, original or artificial one?

Answer (score 0):

The RichTextArea use an iframe for doing the rich text editor.
The PreviewNativeEvent is preview just for the current page.
You can try to add a mask before the textarea for catch the event. The mask is just a div which take all the screen with a transparent backgroud.
The popup panel has a mask option, try to use it :

```
final PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(false, true); // Create a modal dialog box that will not auto-hide
popup.add(new Label("Please wait"));
popup.setGlassEnabled(true); // Enable the glass panel
popup.center(); // Center the popup and make it visible
```